# How to prevent concurrency issue in UPDATE via iBatis

Tags: spring, concurrency, struts2, ibatis

Our Java EE web application performs database operations using iBatis (ORM). The database operation flow is as below

***Flow*** :   JSP --->Action--->ServiceIMpl--->DaoImpl---->Calling update query thru' IBatis

***Note***: The Action, Service & DAO classes are instantiated using Spring 2.5's Dependency Injection technique. We use Struts2.

***Problem***: 2 concurrent users search for the same record and User1 updates Attribute1 while User2 updates Attribute2. User1 first clicks on 'Save' and then User2 clicks on save (they follow each other with a difference of few seconds). When we see the data in database, only the User1's update is present. The Audit columns also show only the User1's update. The User2's update on Attribute2 is not done , at the sametime, no Exceptions are thrown.

We tried using the begin transaction and commit transaction in iBatis surrounding the invokation of the update query defined in the sqlmap xml. The same issue persists. We also tried removing those transaction commands, yet the problem persists.

Should we do anything special/different to handle concurrency during updates ? Wouldn't ORMs like iBatis handle by themselves ?

***Additional Info***: Further investigation revealed the following information.

When User1 & User2 clicks on the a record, it's complete data is fetched for viewing.

Now when both User1 & User2 changes few attributes and click save (concurrently), say first User1's data is updated and then while User2's data is being updated, the already updated data of User1 is over-written & lost.

***`What approach is usually followed in such screens to handle such scenarios ?`***

Comment: This isn't really a struts2 question. Don't know iBatis but it is strange no exception is thrown, increase the logging level if possible. Find out what locking scheme is being used, consider optimistic locking.

Comment: @Quaternion i have updated the question with few more updates..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is not with transactions, it is that before you modify something you must be sure that no one has modified since you last read it.

In web applications you should use [optimistic locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). Basically, you have a "version" field in your table, that has an initial value at `insert` (tipically 1), and gets incremented with each `update`. The procedure is:

1. Read data from the table, *including the version field*
2. Send data the client side, including the version field
3. Receive modified data from the client, including the version field **unchanged**
4. Update the table *and increment the version*, **but only if the version field in the row is the same as the original one received from the client**. That is, where you had

   ```
   update
   ... 
   where id = :id_from_client
   ```

   , now you should do

   ```
   update 
   ..., 
   version = version + 1 
   where 
   id = :id_from_client and 
   version = :version_from_client
   ```
5. Get number of updated rows (you can usually get this information right from the update operation of your persistence framework). If number of updated rows is 1, the operation succeded. If number of updated rows is 0, you should signal a concurrency error.

An example:

1. User1 get the data, with version = 17
2. User2 get the data, with version = 17
3. User1 atomically (atomicity comes from being a single SQL statement):

   - Check if version = 17
   - Updates the data
   - Sets version to 18
4. User2 atomically:

   - Check if version = 17
   - As version was really 18, signals a concurrency error and aborts the operation, informing the user that the operation could not be completed due to somebody else modifying the same data.

Most current persistence frameworks have support for this out of the box and mostly automatically (see [JPA @Version annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Version.html), for example). iBatis seems not to have it, but as it is very close to SQL, you should not have many problems implementing it yourself. See this blog entry for [some details about optimistic locking with iBatis](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:y6cpaqUMAGYJ:matejtymes.blogspot.com/2010/11/optimistic-locking-on-ibatis.html%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=iceweasel-a).

With this scheme, you will not get lost updates, the only problem is that some specific cases will annoy the users a lot: imagine you spend 5 minutes completing some form only to be told at the very end that your operation could not be completed and you need to retry from the start!! In these few cases, you should implement something more sophisticated on top of optimistic locking. I would use some sort of *remote resource leasing* (links??):

1. The client requests a *lease* for the data to the server.
2. If the data is already leased to another client, signal a concurrency error.
3. Else grant the lease to the client *for a finite amount of time*.
4. Before lease expiration, the server grants the client exclusive access to the data. The client can also request a lease renewal (via AJAX, for example). The server can accept or deny the renewal. (Lease times and renewal policies should be decided by the server depending on the specific use case that is being dealt with).
5. The lease expires (this can be done with a scheduled task at the server, for example). When the lease expires, the data should be considered "unlocked", and the server should deny access to the client unless the client is granted a new lease.

This way, your users can be informed that someone is modifying the same data *before they even start* whatever lengthy operation they were trying to complete.

Comment: +1 The lease system that you describe is an implementation of pessimistic locking at the service level.  This is one of the easiest systems to implement (and a good one). A more challenging system would be to leave optimistic locking, if a collision occurs the user is presented with enough data to reconcile the situation if needed. The user interface can get quite a bit trickier. Another system (implementable by JPA via listeners) is to register each interested client and apply ownership to the record, the twist is implementing a "yank" feature that lets you steal ownership.

Comment: You are right, it's just that saying "pessimistic locking" implies locking indefinitely at the DB level to many people (myself included). I prefer calling "lease" to the approaches similar to what I described, and leave "pessimistic locking" for `LOCK TABLE...`, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and those kind of things.

Comment: thank you for you time to provide such a detailed answer. While reading about the Optimistic & Pessimistic locking concepts, i was also looking around if iBatis ORM will support any such features out-of-the-box, but looks like it does not, unlike JPA ORM.

Comment: i have started looking out options to include Optimistic locking feature as a re-usable feature using AOPs in Spring or using AspectJ .. any pointers/directions are welcome....

Answer (score 2):

**Ibatis** does not perform locking .Seeing yours scenario  optimistic locking can solve the problem.To achieve optimistic locking you can have  options.
1.Use framework that support for transaction management like **org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.
DataSourceTransactionManager**.They provide propagation behaviour and isolation level.But,the datasource you are using must support propagation level and isolation level.Spring provides following isolation level.
.ISOLATION_DEFAULT
.ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED
.ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED
.ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ
.ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE.
2.Next you can provide yours implementation of optimistic locking.