# How to synchronize database access in Spring

Tags: mysql, database, spring, servlets, jdbc

I encounter a problem on accessing and updating data on mySQL in Spring framework, and I want to ask everyone the most efficient way to lock a TABLE row.

Let's say I have two tables: one records all circles with their ids and positions, the other records all squares with the same columns. each circle's position can be modified independently, so do the squares. But squares' positions can also be adjusted by moving the position of the circles. pseudo-code as following:

```
Public ShapeMovingService{

   @Transaction (isolation=required) 
   public moveCirclePosition(int id, int newPosition){
       //move circle=id to a new position
       //also move the square which relates to this circle accordingly
    }
   @Transaction (isolation=required) 
   public moveSquarePosition(int id, int newPosition){
       //move square=id to a new position
    }   
}


public CircleDao extends JdbcTemplateSupport{
    public updatePosition(int id, int position){
       //query a circle from circle TABLE with id
       //update the position of the circle
       //ALSO: modify the position of the square which relates to this circle
    }

} 

public SquareDao extends JdbcTemplateSupport{
        public updatePosition(int id, int position){
           //query a square from squareTABLE with id
           //update the position of the square               
        }
}
```

I made several threads to do the following tasks:

- Two threads keep updating the position of the circle id=1
- One thread keeps updating the position of the circle id=2
- One thread keeps updating the position of the square id=1
- One thread keeps updating the position of the square id=2

Moving the position of the circle id=2 will affect the position square id=1; circle id=1 has no relation to other squares, neither does square id=2.

My question is, at which point should I lock the database operation, either by transaction annotation or synchronized keyword, so that no data corruption will occur? Yet different circles can still be updated simultaneously. Right now I lock the updatePosition function, but that means only one circle/square can be updated at a time.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explore about hibernate version-type field, it can solve the purpose, and If you are not using hibernate, then can think of implementing the same as part of the your base dao.

Let know if you need details.

Comment: Would you mind be more specific on version-type field? I am not using Hibernate at this point. Thanks

Comment: Well if we talk about a version-type field, you can have a timestamp column in your tables, which you want to protect, And make sure that after each insert or update to a row, the timestamp field is updated with the current one (same query). Now during next update or insert have a check for the this field if current date is less than what you are already having (means the row was already updated), else have a trigger for that table which works on before update, check for timestamp field and raise error if date in query is less than what is already been help by row.

Comment: I see the logic now, thank you very much. So is Hibernate capable of doing such checking by itself without all the hassles from programmer?

Comment: Yep that's the way it is. For the same you can refer to lots of online tutorials. Just some annotations and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do Pessimistic and optimistic locking.Spring supports for locking .see 
[How to prevent concurrency issue in UPDATE via iBatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12613621/how-to-prevent-concurrency-issue-in-update-via-ibatis/14934598#14934598).

Comment: Thanks. I tried the Spring transaction manager, but it couldn't solve this issue.

Comment: Which data source are you using?.Be aware that not all data sources support all the isolation levels.You need to consult the documentation of yours data source which isolation level are available.

Comment: Either you can provide yours implementation of locking  using time stamp concept of database .Compare time stamp before any operation for every thread requesting DB operation.