# Java field guessing

Tags: java, database, class

I'm working on a small Java library that extract data from databases.

Suppose to have a *generic* Java class:

public class MyClass {

```
   public int valueA;
   public String valueB;
   public Double valueC;

   //getter and setter methods.
}
```

After that I define an SQL query string and I get the class of the generic class `MyClass`.

```
String sql = "Select c.valueA, c.valueB, c.valueC from my_table c";
Class<MyClass> type = MyClass.class;
List<MyClass> results = extractData(sql, type)M
```

Where the method `extractData` is something like the following method:

```
public<T> List<T> extractData(String sql, Class<T> type){
  //1)Do everything that is necessary to retrieve a ResultSet by the sql String.   
  //2)Then, for each row in the ResultSet
  //2.1)Create a new instance of object of type T.
  //2.2)Automatically matches the field name from the query
  //   with the field name of the specified class.
  //2.3) add the object to the list to be returned.
  //3) return the list of results of type T.
}
```

**In practice, if possible, how can I implement step 2.2?**

I guess that this is possible, since I use this approach into a PHP framework.

Comment: Look for 'reflection'. It looks like you're building an ORM mapper. It might be worth it to look at existing solutions. They aren't all as heavy as JPA/Hibernate, for example consider ibatis or google around.

Comment: I'll get a look to both of them! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is *result set metadata* (to get the names of the columns), and *reflection* to analyze the class and set the fields. Expect to write a lot of glue code in between (e.g. from the field types of the class you need to guess which getXXX()/datatype you use for each column).

Its not overly complicated, but requires some thought. There are many potential edge cases (e.g. inheritance) and how to handle implicit type conversions (when class field and column data type are not directly compatible).

Comment: You are right! Moreover he can resort to `java.sql.Types` to define the utility class that invokes the type-based setter/getter methods. This is a one-hour job! Of course, he needs the classes from `java.lang.reflect` to resolve the getter/setter method names. Finally, an ORM would be better, since it embeds a lot of nice features, but I do agree that it is not a must!

Comment: An ORM essentially does the same thing (a bit more elaborate, with a lot of sugar on top, but the principle is absolutely the same), I assume the TC wants to do this as a learning experience or it is an assignment. For a normal project using an ORM saves time and gray hair in debugging.

Comment: I do agree with your point of view. It's the same of mine, but a little bit ameliorated. I just want to point out that an ORM usually makes a view of the selected DB by generating the classes that represent the tables. Then, with a query (generally provided by a query builder) one can easily get the object(s) from the represented table.

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to use a third party [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) mapper here.

[Check out this list of frameworks on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software)

Also, read this thread, as these are two of the best and the answers are great: [Hibernate Vs iBATIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984548/hibernate-vs-ibatis)

- [Hibernate main page](http://www.hibernate.org/)
- [iBATIS main page](http://ibatis.apache.org/)