# Difference between ibatis and mybatis

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

What is the difference between iBatis and myBatis? Where can I find a perfect example of those?

Answer (score 47):

MyBatis is a fork from iBATIS, and according to Wikipedia most of iBATIS' developers moved over to MyBatis too. The iBATIS project is currently marked as Inactive, therefore you should go with MyBatis for new projects and only use iBATIS if you're maintaining an existing project which already uses iBATIS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MyBatis

> MyBatis is a fork of iBATIS 3.0 and is maintained by a team that includes the original creators of iBATIS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBATIS

> On May 21, 2010 the development team forked the code creating a new project called MyBatis and making new releases there. As a consequence the Apache iBATIS project became inactive and was moved to the Apache Attic in June 2010.

Answer (score 5):

It is the same thing, a persistence framework! But until June 2010, *iBatis* was under *Apache license* and since then, the framework founders decided to move it to *Google Code* and they renamed it to **MyBatis**.

The framework is still the same though, it just has a different name now. (of course it should be kept in mind that when time pass, components/features etc, might get updated, so there are more powerful functions added to **MyBatis**).

Answer (score 0):

1.Development team: iBatis was developed by the Apache Foundation, and MyBatis is a branch of iBatis maintained by the original Google team of iBatis.

2.Configuration method: iBatis uses complex XML configuration, while MyBatis simplifies the configuration of XML and annotations, making SQL statement writing and debugging more convenient.

3.Flexibility: MyBatis has higher flexibility compared to iBatis. MyBatis allows you to directly write native SQL statements, while iBatis requires encapsulating SQL statements in XML.

4.Plugin mechanism: MyBatis provides a plugin mechanism, allowing developers to extend the functionality of MyBatis through plugins, while iBatis does not have such a mechanism.

5.Dynamic SQL: MyBatis supports more powerful dynamic SQL statements, which can generate SQL statements at runtime, while iBatis has weaker dynamic SQL capabilities.
Community activity: As MyBatis is a successor product to iBatis, MyBatis has a higher community activity and update speed than iBatis.

Overall, MyBatis outperforms iBatis in terms of functionality and ease of use, making it an improved version of iBatis.