# ibatis resultMap properties vs java pojo variables

Tags: jakarta-ee, ibatis

I need some clarification on the following as I just took over an old j2Ee project and am studying the codes, plus I had no experience in ibatis. Sorry for the noob question but I searched for 2 days with no answers.

Example:
I have a pojo class :

```
public class Document
{
          private int _id;
          private string _title;
          ..........
}
```

DB Table :

```
CREATE TABLE [Documents] (
       [Document_ID] [int] NOT NULL ,
       [Document_Title] [varchar] (32) NULL ,
)
```

Mapping :

```
<resultMap id="document" class="Document">
     <result property="id" column="Document_ID"/>
     <result property="title" column="Document_Title"/>
</resultMap>
```

Question :

I noticed that in the declaration of the id and title variables(in java),there was a underscore in front(I have instances where the underscore was behind, eg.title) but in the resultmap, the underscore is not there. I'm curiuos how it's Mapping is done since the 2 doesn't match exactly.

Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Do you have `auto-mapping=true` in your ibatis mapping file

Comment: Yes ...auto-mapping=true. I realised that ibatis actually calls the setter methods when mapping the properties to the variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [MyBatis is a fork from iBATIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535900/difference-between-ibatis-and-mybatis).

In simple cases `MyBatis` can `auto-map` the results for you and in others you will need to build a result map. But you can also mix both strategies. Let's have a deeper look at how `auto-mapping` works.

When `auto-mapping` results MyBatis will get the `column name` and look for a property with the same name *ignoring case*. That means that if a column named `ID` and property named `id` are found, `MyBatis will set the id property with the ID column value.`

Usually `database columns` are named using *uppercase letters & underscores between words* `java properties` often follow the *camel-case naming convention.* To enable the auto-mapping between them set the setting `mapUnderscoreToCamelCase` to `true`.

Auto-mapping works even when there is an specific result map. When this happens, for each result map, all columns that are present in the ResultSet that have not a manual mapping will be auto-mapped, then manual mappings will be processed.

In the following sample `id & userName` columns `will be auto-mapped` and `hashed_password column will be mapped`.

```
<select id="selectUsers" resultType="User">
  select
    user_id             as "id",
    user_name           as "userName",
    hashed_password
  from some_table
  where id = #{id}
</select>

<resultMap id="userResultMap" type="User">
  <result property="password" column="hashed_password"/>
</resultMap>
```

There are three auto-mapping levels:

```
NONE - disables auto-mapping. Only manually mapped properties will be set.
PARTIAL - will auto-map results except those that have nested result mappings defined inside (joins).
FULL - auto-maps everything.
```

FYIP refer [How Auto-Mapping Works](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Auto-mapping)