# How to use ibatis in spring boot application using annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, ibatis

I am using spring boot in my application, i want to know how to use Spring boot, iBatis and MySQL. While i am trying to find the reference for Spring boot with iBatis projects its automatically redirect to myBatis. I need a example project or site for referring this. I have example for mybatis but i want ibatis with spring boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you shouldn't think how you may connect them. Just read docs about iBatis(MyBatis). But the following link special for you http://www.mybatis.org/spring-boot-starter/mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure/

Comment: mybatis is ibatis (it is the newer version).

Comment: @Karthikeyan, look at https://ibatis.apache.org/, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28535900/difference-between-ibatis-and-mybatis#28535954