# how hibernate caching works when data changes

Tags: hibernate, caching

I wonder how hibernate caching works when the content changes in DB?

What I mean is how does hibernate internally handles the case of two identical queries, when between them there was an update query which changed the expected resultset?

Answer (score 0):

The links below provide the information you seek.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/337099/5280105
[http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm%20http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_caching.htm)

Comment: We're the links helpful at all?