# when will the data be stored in the Second level cache?

Tags: hibernate, caching, second-level-cache

i know that the data will be stored in first level context when we persist it. My question is when will the data be stored in the Second level cache?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are First and Second Level caching in Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337072/what-are-first-and-second-level-caching-in-hibernate)

Comment: Most of the time, the first-level cache, just as the second-level cache, is filled when loading data from the database, not when persisting new entities.