# Spring-Boot - Activating Hibernate 2nd Level Cache

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, ehcache

i am trying to activate Hibernate 2nd Level Cache on a Spring-Boot Application that uses spring-boot-starter-data-jpa. I use Ehcache 2 and have hibernate-ehcache in my classpath for that

I used the following properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

Also i created ehcache.xml in src/main/resources like this (just a test with a cache that never expires)

```
<ehcache updateCheck="false" monitoring="autodetect"
     dynamicConfig="true">

  <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="100000"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
        eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="false">
  </defaultCache>
</ehcache>
```

Also the Entity is Annotated with `@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)` and in the logfile I can clearly see that the default cache is used for the Entity, so it seems to recognize the Annotation and initialize the cache as usual.

```
WARN .h.c.e.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory : HHH020003: Could not find a specific ehcache configuration for cache named [at.test.demo.persistence.entity.Employee]; using defaults.
```

Now to test this I wrote a simple Test that inserts 3 Employees and loads them using usual JPA-Entitymanager. After that I am trying to verify that the loaded Employee actually really got into the Cache, by calling this:

```
Assert.assertTrue(em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().contains(Employee.class, employeeId));
```

But that always fails. Also the SessionFactory-Staticstics shows zeros for everything, that cant be right.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I stripped down the project and added it to public gitlab repo for you to reproduce it: https://gitlab.com/matrium00/reproduce-cache-issue

There is a single unit test for this that fails right now because of the problem.

**EDIT2**
Here is an example of a working XML configuration of em-factory **without** Spring-Boot. I know I could create the necessary beans in my Configuration-Class manually, but there has to be a better way:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
      autowire="byName" depends-on="flyway">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="at.my.package.demo.persistence.entity"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${jdbc.schema}</prop>

            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">${hibernate.generate_statistics}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: The configuration looks good. Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: I editet my question and added a gitlab link with a sample project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the [`@Transactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation on your test method and [`@DataJpaTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) (which means `@Transactional` too) on your test class.

As there is a single transaction, there will be a single session. When you are accessing the same persistent object inside of the same transaction, Hibernate uses first level cache (session cache). To take a hit in the second level cache, you should have different sessions (different transactions).

Simple replace of `@DataJpaTest` with `@SpringBootTest` and remove of `@Transactional` from test method makes test to work.

See also:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/337099/5449250) about first and second level caches.
- [This tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-second-level-cache) about second level cache.